# Wordpress admin showing 0 posts

Tags: wordpress, plugins, admin, posts

My wordpress admin is showing 0 posts, pages, categories, & tags. However, everything is appearing on the frontend just fine. I'm running wordpress 3.0 and as far as I know no settings have been changed, plugins upgraded, etc since this began happening.

Also, when searching for plugins I get the error "An Unexpected HTTP Error occurred during the API request." I'm assuming this is related to the first problem, but it may not be.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your WP core files may have been corrupted during FTP'ing, do you have a URL?

To fix the API request:

1) Login to your FTP server

2) Go to wp-includes and edit class-http.php

3) Find: ‘timeout’ => apply_filters( ‘http_request_timeout’, 5),

4) Change the value “5” to “30”, the value is actually is the number of seconds before the server times out.

5) It should be this: ‘timeout’ => apply_filters( ‘http_request_timeout’, 30),

Comment: The site has been up and running for like 6 months with no problem. It just recently began doing this. Could it still be because of FTP corruption? The frontend is fully-functional at http://bit.ly/htZJdj

Comment: @Brett - See above for API fix :)